# How exactly was Zoltun Kulle nerfed to stop abuse?

Tags: diablo-iii

Before there was a way to gain levels quickly, keep repeating Zoltun Kulle quests again and again (usually with a friend).

I've heard it no longer works.

What changes did Blizzard make to make sure it doesn't work?

Comment: this is two questions in one. please seperate them and fix it.

Comment: Blizzard reduced the XP from completing the quests for killing Zoltun Kulle on all difficulties except normal as far as I know.

Comment: The second question's already been asked by you, and duped.  I've removed that from this question.

Comment: Where's the duplicate question then?

Answer (score 4):

Just like any other Experience runs they had earlier, they broke down the Quest reward experience greatly.

The old tactic was to do the run with multiple friends so you could chain-join each other's new games, without completing the initial quest.

Each player that would just the other player's their new game would be able to complete it again and again, until all games were completed.

After all rounds were done the runner (player who did the killing each time) would just restart and the circle was complete.

Personally I think, if you're patient, it's still a pretty good leveling method for very low levels. And at certain breakpoints when you hit the next difficulty. Probably 1-12~, 20-30~, 38-48~.

Comment: what do you mean broke down. Bring down?

Comment: Yes, "broke down" as in "reduced" :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that repeating the same quests again and again yield much lower xp gain.

For example, first time complete it got 20k xp. Next few times completing it get 8k something.,